# Stop Camera Rotation During Wild Battle

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-seventh-generation

When attempting to find shiny variations of Pokemon, using the new "Call for Help" feature, I often find that within seconds the camera starts to jump around in what I can only describe as an "action camera" style mode with various close-ups, moving shots, different angles of what is going on.

I find that if I need to look away from the screen that this can result in having to wait a while before the camera sets focus on both Pokemon - side by side - so that I can visually inspect if one is what I'm after.  I also find it somewhat nauseating after prolonged periods of time.

Is there anyway to turn this feature off and just have the game camera focus on the 1 / 2 opponents?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, there is no way to turn these camera angles off. You'll just have to wait until you get a view of the wild Pokémon again.

Comment: That is unfortunate, but thanks for letting me know.